# Android: NFC: AAR and data: Starting an application with extra data

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, android-applicationrecord

I'm looking into some NFC functionality,

I would like to embed two ndef messages inside my tag.

1. An Android Application Record
2. Plain text data

I would like to create the following scenario:

1. Tap a tag
2. Start my application based on the Android Application Record embedded inside the tag
3. In my activity retrieve more information from the tag (from NFC, or the intent system, etc.?)

I was wondering if it is possible?

Comment: are you able to write on your own NFC Tag?

Comment: @RafaelT yes, why wouldn`t it be possible?

Comment: Because most of the NFC Tags are 'read-only'. it should be definitly possible. Just create your NdefMessages and write them on your Card.

Comment: Put the AAR as the last record in the NDEF message. That way non-Android devices and pre-ICS Android devices will still be able to discover the text record.

Comment: I know this is quite old, but did you manage to do it in the end? I am looking for the exact same scenario, but cannot figure it out at the moment, and the links of ThomasRS did not seem helpful in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created an [NFC Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin) exactly for this scenario. You will also find an Android boilerplate project in the downloads section for the same project.

You might  want to check out [NDEF Tools for Android](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/), and do a search on the app store for read and write apps.